# Spark : spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException - ShuffleMapStage

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, emr

I am running a spark job in yarn-cluster and which runs 2.5 hour and gets killed and throw Exception.

I have a df = [CUSTOMER_ID ,itemType, eventTimeStamp, valueType, value ]

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+--------------------+
| CUSTOMER_ID | itemType  | valueType   | value  | eventTimeStamp     |
+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------+
| 1           |  rent     |  dvd        |  12    |2016-09-19T00:00:00Z
| 1           |  rent     |  dvd        |  12    |2016-09-19T00:00:00Z
| 1           | buy       |  tv         |  12    |2016-09-20T00:00:00Z
| 1           |  rent     |  movie      |  12    |2016-09-20T00:00:00Z
| 1           |   buy     |  movie      |  12    |2016-09-18T00:00:00Z
| 1           | buy       |  movie      |  12    |2016-09-18T00:00:00Z
+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+---------------------+
```

I would like to get the result as :

```
 CUSTOMER_ID : 1
    totalValue  : 72 --- group by based on id
    itemTypeMap : {"rent" : 3, "buy" : 3} --- group by based on id
    valueTypeMap : {"dvd" : 2, "tv" : 1, "movie" : 3 } --- group by based on id
    itemTypeForDay : {"rent: 2, "buy" : 2 }  --- group By based on id and dayofmonth(col("eventTimeStamp"))  atmost 1 type per day
```

My Code :

```
  val temp = df.groupBy("CUSTOMER_ID").agg(
          collectAsList(df("itemType")).alias("itemCount"),
          collectAsList(df("valueType")).alias("valueTypeCount"),
          sum("value") as "totalValues")


        val stage1  =  temp.withColumn("valueTypeMap", count_by_value(col("valueTypeCount")))
          .withColumn("itemTypeMap", count_by_value(col("itemCount")))
          .drop("itemCount")
         .drop("valueTypeCount")

    val toMap = udf { (typ: String, count: Int) => Map(typ -> count) }

 val count_by_value = udf {( value :scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => if (value == null) null else  value.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)}

    val collectAsList = new CollectListFunction(StringType)


        import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{dayofmonth, countDistinct}



        val stage2 = df.groupBy("CUSTOMER_ID", "itemType")
          .agg(countDistinct(dayofmonth(col("eventTimeStamp"))) as "daysPeritemType")
          .withColumn("itemTypeForDay", toMap(col("itemType"), col("daysPeritemType")))
          .groupBy("CUSTOMER_ID").agg(CombineMaps(col("itemTypeForDay")) as "resultMap")

        val result = stage1.join(stage2, stage1("CUSTOMER_ID") === stage2("CUSTOMER_ID"))
          .drop(stage2("CUSTOMER_ID"))

TestPairFucntion.saveAsTempFile(convertToRDD(result))
```

Util classes :

```
 case class Data(totalValue: Long, typeCount: Map[String,Int], typeForDay: Map[String,Int] ,itemCount : Map[String,Int]) extends Serializable

     def convertToRDD(result : DataFrame): RDD[(String, String)] = {

        val tempFile = result.map( {
          r => {
            val customerId = r.getAs[String]( "CUSTOMER_ID" )
            val totalValue = r.getAs[Long]( "totalValue" )

            val typeCount = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]]( "typeCount" )
            val itemCount = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]]( "itemCount" )
            val typeForDay = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]]( "typeForDay" )


            val features = Data( totalValue, typeCount, typeForDay, itemCount)

            val jsonString = JacksonUtil.toJson( features )

            (customerId, jsonString)
          }
        } )

        return tempFile
      }

class CollectListFunction[T] (val colType: DataType) extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

  def inputSchema: StructType =
    new StructType().add("inputCol", colType)

  def bufferSchema: StructType =
    new StructType().add("outputCol", ArrayType(colType))

  def dataType: DataType = ArrayType(colType)

  def deterministic: Boolean = true

  def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    buffer.update(0, new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[T])
  }

  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    val list = buffer.getSeq[T](0)
    if (!input.isNullAt(0)) {
      val sales = input.getAs[T](0)
      buffer.update(0, list:+sales)
    }
  }

  def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
    buffer1.update(0, buffer1.getSeq[T](0) ++ buffer2.getSeq[T](0))
  }

  def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    buffer.getSeq[T](0)
  }
}



object CombineMaps extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  override def inputSchema: StructType = new StructType().add("map", dataType)
  override def bufferSchema: StructType = inputSchema
  override def dataType: DataType = MapType(StringType, IntegerType)
  override def deterministic: Boolean = true

  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = buffer.update(0 , Map[String, Int]())

  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    val before = buffer.getAs[Map[String, Int]](0)
    val toAdd = input.getAs[Map[String, Int]](0)
    val result = before ++ toAdd
    buffer.update(0, result)
  }

  override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = update(buffer1, buffer2)

  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = buffer.getAs[Map[String, Int]](0)
}
```

My Config :

```
spark.driver.cores  30
spark.driver.memory 200g
spark.executor.cores    16
spark.executor.instances    40
spark.executor.memory   60g
spark.memory.fraction   0.95
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead  2000
```

This is the error I keep getting :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 3 (map at <console>:130) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Connection from ip-172-31-10-34.ec2.internal/172.31.10.34:7337 closed
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$4.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$4.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:152)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection from ip-172-31-10-34.ec2.internal/172.31.10.34:7337 closed
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportResponseHandler.java:124)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportChannelHandler.java:94)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:739)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:659)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1258)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1637)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner$.sketch(Partitioner.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner.<init>(Partitioner.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions$$anonfun$sortByKey$1.apply(OrderedRDDFunctions.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions$$anonfun$sortByKey$1.apply(OrderedRDDFunctions.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions.sortByKey(OrderedRDDFunctions.scala:61)
    at com.spark.TestPairRDDFunctions.saveAsRODB(TestPairRDDFunctions.scala:62)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:149)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:154)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:156)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:158)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:160)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:162)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:164)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:166)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:168)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:170)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:172)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:174)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:176)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:178)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:180)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:182)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:184)
    at <init>(<console>:186)
    at .<init>(<console>:190)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:664)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:629)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:622)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.interpret(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:57)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:276)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:170)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:118)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

com.spark.TestPairRDDFunctions.saveAsTempFile(TestPairRDDFunctions.scala:62)has this line (this is a dependency)

```
    self.map(kv => (kv._1.toString, kv._2.toString)).sortByKey().map(kv => kv._1 + "\t" + kv._2).saveAsTextFile(TmpDir)
```

I can able to get `stage1` and I believe the issue is with `stage2`.

Comment: Can you execute `stage2` on its own and see if it passes?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski it works with small data set but not with big

Comment: How big is your big dataset? Can you reproduce it? Where is your dataset coming from? Are you caching/persisting?

Comment: The data size is 2.4 TB. I can reproduce it when ever I try to read the big data set